# How to get the ID of a form new record in Access?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I try to get the ID when I open a form with a new record.
So I use this kind of code :

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "myform", , , , acFormAdd
```

But when I am in the opened form, how to get the new ID created by Access, as the field is an AutoNumber ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the new ID?

Comment: I have to use it to insert in other table which have referential integrity. Don't know if it is possible or not, but sure if I don't have the ID to do this, it will be much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have started entering the record, the ID will be available using VBA code:

```
Me.ID
```

or

```
Me.<name of control bound to ID field>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I saw this code above somewhere else, and it didn't work. I don't know why, I have this error, in French : "Membre de méthode ou de données introuvable" which could be translated by "Method member or datas unfound" which is the error 461

Comment: This is a problem with VBA not recognising fields in the record source. Remove the value of the `RecordSource` property (your table or query), save and then put back the value into `RecordSource`.

Comment: Sorry for the time taken. Even if I do what you said, it is not working at all :/

Comment: It is a quirk of Ms Access :( . Open and close Access, tickle it, throttle it, compile it, repair and compact it. Try again what I wrote above. Eventually the intellisense will show the `ID` field and it will work.

Comment: It doesn't wanna hear anything. Thanks for your help, but I guess MS Access is stronger than us.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?